# Error in connecting to database when running an application

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I created a database named ABC.mdf in SSMS-2012 which used windows authentication mode. Using this, I created an application in Visual Studio 2010 and then published it (creating the .exe files). When I installed SQL Express 2012 in another computer and ran the executable, this error message was shown

[image]

The connection string used in VB was:

```
 ConnectionString = "Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\ABC.mdf; Database=ABC.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

So I copied the database files exactly in the C drive. How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Open up services applet or SQL Server configuration manager and check which instances are installed and running. Always TRY ... CATCH the Connection.Open :)

Comment: The thing is that in the computer where i created the database had a different server name and instance name and the computer where i'm running the executable has a different instance and server name. Is the problem due to this issue?

Comment: Moreover, the server name is always based on the computer's name... so there will always be a difference in the server name.

Comment: If it's always a local server, use a dot (as you already did). But must change the instance name (the part after the backslash) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that SQLExpress is installed on that server as the proper named instance. If not possible, change the .\Sqlexpress in the connection string to SQLSERVERNAME\SQLexpress where SQL server name is the name of the machine where it worked before you moved.

. Stands for localhost by default.

Comment: I used the default instance for both i.e MSSQLSERVER

Comment: Open up services applet or SQL Server configuration manager and check which instances are installed and running.